# php domxml error with google map

Tags: php, xml, dictionary

my server PHP Version 5.1.6 domxml is enable but when i try to execute

```
// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);
```

it return fatel error

```
Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()
```

my server php info is

```
    dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.6.26
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
```

Comment: did you check if it's enabled in the SAPI version of PHP? looks like you're doing `phpinfo` at the command line, which uses a completely separate .ini file.

Comment: @AmalMurali, PHP 4 was bundled with domxml, PHP 5 is not. So obviously the value will be false.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Yeah, that command is only useful if you're on PHP4. Deleted it. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali, You are pretty talented. All your answers are nice :)

Comment: Where should that function come from? Please provide reference that it exists. Also I do not think that Stackoverflow is a fitting venue to ask questions about longtime-dead PHP versions this year, neither it is for support requests (*"any one can help to fix this issue"*). This is rather special interest. I suggest to close against the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to do this.

**[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**

DOM XML was deprecated in favor of this. It follows the W3C specification so you have typical DOM methods such as `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementById`, `appendChild`, `removeChild`, etc. It also uses appropriate classes such as `DOMElement`, `DOMNode` and `DOMNodeList`.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('markers'));

// output
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

If you know already how to traverse the DOM in Javascript you pretty much already know how to do it in PHP using DOMDocument and other related classes.

I don't know why Shankar's answer was downvoted unless there are people who favor the next method.

**[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)**

SimpleXML attempts to live up to its name by using only two classes and using a parent-child structure to traverse the document.

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<markers/>');

// output
echo $doc->asXML();
```

An element in itself evaluates to its contents if it's treated as a string, and attributes can be accessed as you would access elements of an associative array.

```
$marker = $doc->addChild('marker');
$marker->addAttribute('color','red');
```

You can also do this if you don't really need to hang onto the reference to the element. You can't add multiple attributes using this method, however, so you'd still need the previous to add new attributes without traversing the whole document.

```
$doc->addChild('marker')->addAttribute('color','red');
```

Access your elements and attributes like so:

```
// red
echo $doc->marker[0]['color'];
```

To set the element value just set it.

```
$doc->marker[0] = 'Text Value';

// Text Value
echo $doc->marker[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of **`DOMDocument`** ?

Change your code

```
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);
```

to

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
$node = $doc->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
```

Comment: i was try this also but not lucky same issue occur

Comment: How come you get the same issue ? There is no way `Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc()` arised from `DOMDocument`